# How to fix `unknown variable 'sql-mode=ANSI'`?

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL 5.5.27, in my.cnf I have:

```
[mysql]
sql_mode=ANSI
```

Upon starting the mysql console I get:

```
unknown variable 'sql-mode=TRADITIONAL'
```

The MySQL doc [Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html) shows that option, so why does it not work?

(If it helps, I am on OSX Lion)

Also, [here is a pastebin showing the things another person has tried, with no solution](http://pastebin.com/Qz7TYGsC).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty certain the reason it isn't working is because it is an argument for mysqld and not the client. I came up with an alternative way that you could do this instead. Edit your users my.cnf `i.e. ~/.my.cnf` to be something like this:

```
[client]
init-command="set sql_mode='TRADITIONAL'"
```

Comment: You can also move the init-command to the command like so `mysql --init-command="set sql_mode='TRADITIONAL'"`. This would allow you to do as an alias and without having to edit my.cnf.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the client that is connecting, but does not work for the server as a whole (the `[mysqld]` in my.cnf).

Comment: There must be a script that starts your mysqld process some where. I'm not familiar with how it would launch on Mac, but on Linux it would be some where in /etc/init.d/. If you can find the script you should just be able to add --sql-mode=XXX to the command line.

Comment: If I add this and try `mysql -e "select @@sql_mode"`, I just get an error: `mysql: unknown variable 'init-command=set sql_mode='TRADITIONAL''`

Comment: alternatively, you can set this command in the `mysqld` section like     [mysql]
sql_mode=TRADITIONAL

Answer (score 23):

`sql-mode` should be in the `[mysqld]` section, not in the `[mysql]` section; if you move `sql-mode=ANSI` to the `[mysqld]` section, it should work.

Comment: You sir are a legend. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In config file you should use `sql-mode` name instead (with dash, not underscore)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode

And as @cogsmos pointed out, you should put it `[mysqld]` section

Comment: Tried that too, but it does not work. Same error. Also, the variable is `Variable Name sql_mode` from the docs. `sql-mode` is to be used when at the comment line, such as `mysql --sql-mode=ANSI` (which also does not work).

Comment: @Zabba: It's not a variable, it's am option file directive thus: `Option-File Format sql-mode`. It should work. Show the exact config with `sql-mode` and the exact error message

Comment: I tried as you said, and restarted the server. The client then connected with no error. But when I run an UPDATE SQL, the option seems to have no effect, any ideas? (I am trying to update 300 chars into a 255 char varchar field and it does not throw any errors)

Comment: @Zabba: `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;`

Comment: That gave 1 row returned, but the value is "blank" i.e. no "NULL" or any other text where the value should be (for both).

Answer (score 0):

Both in Mysql and mariadb you can try to put in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file in the section:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=''
```

for me it solved.