# Not able to set sql_mode to none

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

I use version 5.7.9 as seen below on mac El Capitan.

```
~  mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.7.9 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I created a file ~/.my.cnf and added the following.

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode =''
```

I restarted mysql and checked sql_mode again but there is no difference. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762308/how-to-get-rid-of-strict-sql-mode-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

---

First edit `my.cnf(ubuntu)` or `my.ini(Windows)`

For ubuntu: `sudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

---

change your settings, save it and close it.

---

Restart mysql : `sudo service mysql restart`
All changes will be saved.

---

Then check again:

---

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```