# How to reset sql_mode at osx 10.11

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, sql-mode

I have a problem with this sql_mode

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
column 'my_database_name.my_table.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns
in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I tried this tutorial, but without result.
[How to get rid of STRICT SQL mode in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762308/how-to-get-rid-of-strict-sql-mode-in-mysql/)

I have a clean instalation of osX 10.11 a I was manually instal apache,
php and mysql like in this tutorial...
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/

My version apache:

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19
```

Mysql version:

```
Server version: 5.7.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

If I at first insert this sql code to my phpmyadmin, then everything works perfectly to next restart os or mysql

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

I tried set my.cnf file in every path like you can see bellow and after restart is still the same problem.

```
$ mysql --help | grep /my
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Please help.
thanks